# Выполнение jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть форма, которая вставлена в окно fancybox. Для валидации (onclick на submit) такой код:

```
if(jQuery(field_id).val()=='')
{
  var d = document.getElementById("email_address");
  d.className = d.className + " validation-failed";
  jQuery(field_id).addClass(" validation-failed");
  console.log(jQuery(field_id));
}
```

Console.log нормально выполняется по нажатию, а остальное почему-то откладывается пока не закрою окно и тогда применяется. При чем даже несколько кликов запоминаются и после закрытися все срабатывают.
В чем может быть косяк и куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косяк нашел. Вызываю окно так:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
  function() {
     jQuery.fancybox( jQuery('#registration-please').html() );
});
```

Он копирует html и под id я получаю не то, что в окне.